# Test cases duplicated throughout multiple test suites in Microsoft Test Manager/TFS 2012

Tags: team-foundation-server

I'm running TFS 2012 with Microsoft Test Manager(MTM) for manual test design and test management.  I've got this annoying issue, I can't seem to figure out.  When I am building my test plans, creating tests and adding them to test suites  -- MTM is adding an instance to the test cases I'm creating throughout other test suites in the same test plan.

For example, I have a test plan with 5 requirements, which I'll call Test Suites 1-5.  Let's say I'm in test suite 3.  To avoid creating each test from scratch, I copy and paste an instance of another test into test suite 3.  This does not create a new test case, but basically just links to the test case instance for the one I copied over.  I then right-click on the test case I copied over and click, "Create copy and add to suite".  This must be done, since MTM does not create a new test case with just copying/pasting.  So, that creates a new test case which I can then modify and save.  Once I save it, that new test case is this added to Test Suite 3, but also Test Suite 1 and 2, but not 4 and 5.  If I did this in test suite 5, it would be duplicated in all Test Suites 1-4.  So it really makes so sense to me what MTM is doing here.

Any ideas?  This will be a nightmare to clean up with features with a lot of reqs.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Joseph, there is no option to stop the duplication of Test cases and any other related work items. thats my take with information you provide above If you could provide me some screen shots of the issue exactly you are experiencing , i might be help you and assist you in this regard.

Thanks.

Nlohchab